# How to add decimal place to last two positions in string? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, number-formatting

I am trying to convert the string `1009` to become `$10.09`. I have been looking at the documentation for NumberHelpers for about 15 minutes now and am a bit surprised that I did not find any methods that can add a decimal point delimiter `.` before the last two positions of a string or integer.

At first, I tried:

```
number_to_currency("1009", :unit => "$")
# => $1,009.00
```

then I tried using:

```
number_to_currency("1009", :unit => "$", :precision => 0)
# => $1,009
```

which only removes digits after the decimal place, but does not shift the decimal place itself. As well, adding `-2` as the precision argument throws `ArgumentError`.

I know this is possible to do with a few lines of JavaScript but I was looking for a more a pure Rails approach, if any.

How would someone be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just divide the number with 100. It's simple and it works. I guess you are converting cents to USD, I don't think there's any  other way around it.

```
number_to_currency("1009".to_f / 100, :unit => "$")
```

You could also write a helper for this, something like...

```
def cents_to_usd(amount)
  number_to_currency(amount.to_f / 100, :unit => "$")
end
```

So that it looks nicer in your views.

Comment: Thank you! So painfully obvious now after you pointed that out. I will be off to my 2nd Grade math course now.

Comment: No problem :) Check out my edit to avoid too much logic in your views.